# How do I concatenate a firstname and a lastname in a select statement? (mySQL)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t.test_id
     , t.appt_date
     , t.appt_time
     , t.appt_site
     , p.process_date
     , p.pool_status
     , t.test_status
      , concat(u.fname + ' ' + u.lname) AS processed_by
  FROM .....
```

I am trying to get the last field to appear as processed_by with a first name and a last name concatenated together but it returns all attempts as 0.

Answer (score 1):

[concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) takes a list of arguments (comma separated) and joins them together. So you would want to do:

```
select concat(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) as processed_by from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a comma to split first and last name `SELECT concat(u.fname, u.lname)`